# Modify the randomNames environment to add/remove names

Tags: r, class

The `randomNames` package in R can be used to generate random first and last names. There is an `environment` called `randomNamesData` that is loaded with the package and `randomNamesData` contains

```
> randomNamesData
<environment: 0x11db12078>
```

Similar output for `str(randomNamesData)` and `dput(randomNamesData)`.

if you examine this `randomNamesData` with `View` you get the following:

```
> View(randomNamesData)
```

[image: Viewing randomNamesData]

The objects in each of these objects (such as `first_names_e1_g0`) is of type `array`.

Is it possible to modify the `randomNamesData` environment to add more names? If it is possible, how to add/remove names to it?

Comment: Environments behave like lists, for the most part. Can you access items in the environment via statements like `randomNamesData$first_names_e1_g0`?

Comment: Yes, I can access `randomNamesData$first_names_e1_g0`, however if I try to add to it by typing `assign(randomNamesData$first_names_e1_g0, "hello")` , I get an error message

Comment: Why not just `randomNamesData$first_names_e1_g0 <- [some value]`?

Comment: @jdobres This will overwrite all the names and replace it with just the single name (or vector of names) entered.

Comment: I don't know your exact goal, but you should be able to do something like `tmp <- randomNamesData$first_names_e1_g0`, then make whatever changes you want to `tmp`, and then `randomNamesData$first_names_e1_g0 <- tmp`.

Comment: I think I get your logic. It's the good old `temp = x`, then `x = temp_after_modifications` way?

Comment: Correct! That's probably the best solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on the exact changes you want to make, but since environments behave like lists, it should be possible to pull the data of interest into a temporary variable, modify that variable, and then replace the original:

```
tmp <- randomNamesData$first_names_e1_g0

[make changes to tmp]

randomNamesData$first_names_e1_g0 <- tmp
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped. More work had to be done however due to the nature of the environment and the way that values are accessed. First it's `temp = object`, then `df.new = runif(n)` ; `names(df.new) = vec_n_names`; and finally `temp = append(temp, df.new)`